# Ненужное преобразование Decimal

Tags: c#, sql, db2

Проблема состоит в следующем:

Есть Data Studio 4.1.3 в которой работаю с DB2, в ней обращаюсь запросом к таблице к столбцу с типом int (содержит сумму в копейках), следующим запросом вывожу сумму в типе Decimal:
`SELECT decimal("SummaCurrAcc" / 100, 20, 2) as "Summa"  from PBI."InfoYSR"`
выводит все правильно:

1. 142168.94
2. 22.79
3. 263326.55

Но! Следующим кодом в VS:

```
public static void Load()
    {
        string sqlExpression = "SELECT decimal(\"SummaCurrAcc\" / 100, 20, 2) as \"Summa\"  from PBI.\"InfoYSR\" FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
        string connectionString = @"DSN=DB; UID=user; PWD=pass; DBQ=DB;";
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
            OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string str = string.Empty;
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        str += reader.GetValue(i);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }

            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Выводит

1. 14216894
2. 2279
3. 26332655

То есть попросту игнорирует преобразование в Decimal в запросе, хочу обратить внимание что столбец в C# по GetFieldType() имеет все-таки тип Decimal, а деление не происходит. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Когда тип int делим на 100 то получаем в итоге тоже тип int. Нужно или сразу преобразовивать или делить на 100.0 
       SELECT decimal("SummaCurrAcc", 20, 2) / 100 as "Summa"  from PBI."InfoYSR"
или
       SELECT "SummaCurrAcc"/ 100.0 as "Summa"  from PBI."InfoYSR"